# What is the minimum price for a full Glass cockpit for the size of 6 passengers aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, avionics, glass-cockpit

I am working on my final project at school and currently looking for the information about avionics system. We design a concept amphibious aircraft with the info as listed below:

- 2 pilots in the cockpit
- 6 passengers
- Aircraft Mission: Leisure/ Passenger Transport/ Cargo
- Cruise speed: 130 knots
- Range: 400 to 600 nm
- Service Ceiling: 14,000 ft

The customer wants the aircraft to be certified by both FAA and TC with installed IFR system. From FAA I got all the requirement for IFR and decided to design a glass cockpit with a budget of 20,000 - 25,000 USD. However, when looking at the different company such as Honeywell, Bendix/King, Garmin, etc., the price is too high for a newly installed glass cockpit. Therefore, I just wonder if there is any cheap, certified (FAA), and safe products available and what are your opinions regarding the idea of glass cockpit design for the mentioned aircraft above. I saw several cheap products from DYNON and ASPEN, but not very sure if their products are certified by FAA.

I really appreciate any help or comments from you guys. thank you!

Comment: Simply, You cannot simultaneously have certified and cheap stuff.

Comment: What will be the surface area of the "monitors" ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can design and certify a single, simple aircraft instrument like an old-school variometer or pressure gauge and stay within a 25,000 USD budget. In fact, I'm pretty sure you *can't*. You probably could pull off the design part (old-school instruments are pretty simple as design and construction go, though the implementation requires precision), but 25,000 USD is probably more in line with what the FAA will bill you to even *start looking at* the design of your single instrument, rather than what certification will cost. *Let alone a whole IFR glass cockpit!*

Comment: DYNON have recently obtained STCs for some of their systems. I believe they are within the budget.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I believe the OP is talking production costs, not development costs. And the FAA provides its services free of charge. It's the cost of providing the data to the FAA that isn't cheap. Also, FAA resources are limited so often you'll need to involve a DER or DAR who will act for the FAA. They do charge for service.

Comment: @Gerry Good point, maybe I should have written "before the FAA will look at your design" to be more generic. My general point still holds, though, in that certification is expensive.

Comment: Why even use a glass panel in the design?  Can you use seam gauges?

Comment: \$25k seems really low. I recently saw a quote to modify a Cessna Caravan to a Garmin digital cockpit suite, that was in the region of \$150k.